# DOT PRODUCT UNIT IN MALI MIDGARD GPUS

Tags: arm, gpu, opencl, dot-product, mali

Hello i am using a mali t-624 gpu (Midgard Family Gpu).
Could you tell me if those gpu's are supporting dot product as I cannot find any info for this.
Also could you tell me a kernel written in opencl that will give me the best time execution for dot product.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The ARM Mali T624 MP4 GPU supports OpenCL 1.1. The [specification](https://www.khronos.org/files/opencl-1-1-quick-reference-card.pdf) includes the dot product for 32-bit floating-point. Use `float dot (floatn p0, floatn p1)` for best execution time.